# What should be the time complexity in nested loop for this particular structure?

Tags: algorithm

```
for i=1 to n:
{
  for j=1 to m:
   {
    some code
   }
}
```

But n is very large in comparison to m. For instance n=1000 and m=5. Logically, it will give O(m*n). Moreover, m is somewhat constant but n varies and is always a big number.
Thus, can I say O(m*n) merges to O(n)? for theoretical analysis

Comment: It depends on what you define as input of your algorithm. If you define n is the size of the input and m is a constant, O(n) is the complexity. If you say n and m are the sizes of your inputs, O(n*m) is the complexity.

Comment: It's not really answerable unless you say what "somewhat constant" means. You can't do a theoretical analysis unless you have defined your terms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only say it is O() when  is guaranteed to be O(1), i.e. there must be a maximum limit for . That limit may be 10, 100, 1000, 10000 or a million, as long as it is a preset constant.